# Add Post Author body class to WordPress

Tags: author

I'm trying to add a custom body class to WordPress which should be the author of the post which is displayed. I looked at different how to's and tried to create some code but it doesn't work:

```
add_filter( 'body_class' , 'ft_add_guest_body_class' );

function ft_add_guest_body_class( $classes ) {

    // add 'wp_admin' to the $classes array

    if (get_the_author() != 'MrX')
        $classes[] = 'wp_admin';

    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;

}
```

The problem is that the `wp_admin` body class is displayed on every page and post. When I remove the conditional the body class is still applied so it must be that.

Comment: Do some debugging then. What does `get_the_author()` return?

Comment: it actually returns nothing...

Comment: that's your problem then. I think this is because the post hasn't been loaded yet. Not sure what the best is to deal with this... I'll flag this for migration to Wordpress.SE, the guys there will know

Comment: Beware the [PHP voodoo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: Did anyone get a working version of this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$author = $wp_query->post->post_author;
$author = get_user_by('id', $author);
author->user_nicename;
```

That should get you the author slug which you can use in your conditional statement. get_the_author can only be used inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're trying to use get_the_author() outside of the Loop. Try using $post->post_author instead, which will return the author's ID for the current post.